# How to get @Output value of a routed child into parent component Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to Angular, and am trying to pass an array in a child component into the parent component.  In the child component, I have the following:

```
export class AoRSummaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
 @Output() fooDetails: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
...
//then the code that builds the array (this.detailsObj.aorDetails)
...
this.fooDetails.emit(this.detailsObj.aorDetails);
```

My question is, what do I include in the parent component html in order to use fooDetails in an *ngFor="let detail of fooDetails" statement?  I don't seem to be able to use `<child-component-selector></child-component-selector>` statements because we are using `<router-outlet>` to load the child component.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the so called "child" component is rendered inside its "parent" through the `router-outlet` directive, then you dont trully have a parent-child relation. A typical solution for this situation is to share a service instance among the related components.

```
@Injectable()
export class FooService{
  private _value$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(42);
  ctor(){}

  get value$(){
    return this._value$.asObservable();
  }

  pushData(v: number){
    this._value$.next(v);
  }
}

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 value$: Observable<number>;
 ctor(private _service: FooService){}

 ngOnInit(){
   this.value$ = this._service.value$();
 }

 //Add ngOnDestroy in case that you manually subscribe to value$
}

export class ChildComponent{
  ctor(private _service: FooService){}

  triggerEvent(v: number){
     this._service.pushData(v);
     // this replaces emitter.emit(v)
  }
}
```

More info about this topic can be found in [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)